# ggplotly-size fixed in shiny? Resizing doesnt work

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, plotly

I try to refit [this](https://plot.ly/r/shinyapp-plotly-events/) shiny app for my purposes. Since I want to add some text above it, I use the Rmd-Format. The following code is completely the same as in the link, except that I deleted the server- and ui-functions, because otherwise you dont see all the output. (Update: I also threw out the click,zoom and brush-events, to make the code more readable)

````
```{r cars, echo=FALSE}
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

fluidPage(
  radioButtons("plotType", "Plot Type:", choices = c("ggplotly", "plotly")),
  plotlyOutput("plot", height = "700px"),
  verbatimTextOutput("hover")
)

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    # use the key aesthetic/argument to help uniquely identify selected observations
    key <- row.names(mtcars)
    if (identical(input$plotType, "ggplotly")) {
      p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, colour = factor(vs), key = key)) + 
        geom_point()
      ggplotly(p) %>% layout(dragmode = "select")
    } else {
      plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~wt, key = ~key) %>%
        layout(dragmode = "select")
    }
  })

  output$hover <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_hover")
    if (is.null(d)) "Hover events appear here (unhover to clear)" else d
  })

```
````

I added `height=700px` to `plotlyOutput`, because I have a bigger dataset and a long legend in my ggplot-graph. However while the plotly graph adjusts - the ggplot-graph does not get bigger than ~500px.

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982025/on-shiny-app-ggplotly-renders-half-the-size-of-plot-ly-how-to-fix-that), this is an issue of `ggplotly`. The problem is that I need to set `height=700px` in `plotlyOutput` to stop the `ggplotly`-graph from overplotting my Text-output. **What I am searching is either:**

1. Another way to stop the overplotting than setting `height=700px` in `plotlyOutput`, or alternatively,
2. Another way to change the size of the `ggplotly`-graph

To achieve the latter I tried adding the height to `ggplotly` to the layout function afterwards. I even [set `autosize=FALSE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44764272/resizing-plotlyoutput-object) in the corresponding `layout`. I also tried to [specify the height in an extra `renderUI`-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693102/how-to-control-plot-height-size-in-interactive-rmarkdown-with-shiny?rq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change plotly attributes after running ggplotly. Not sure if you meant that as adjusting layouts though, but if so, then I couldn't replicate your problem as it gets more than 500 absolutely fine.

For instance, in this case:

```
pt<-ggplotly(p) %>% layout(dragmode = "select")
# have a look to all attributes
str(pt)

#Specifically height is
pt$height<-700
```

You can test the difference: 500 for plotly and 700 for ggplotly (don't set up height in `plotlyOutput` itself)

```
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    # use the key aesthetic/argument to help uniquely identify selected observations
    key <- row.names(mtcars)
    if (identical(input$plotType, "ggplotly")) {
      p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, colour = factor(vs), key = key)) + 
        geom_point()
      pt<- ggplotly(p) %>% layout(dragmode = "select")
      pt$height<-700
      pt
      # ggplotly(p) %>% layout(dragmode = "select")
    } else {
      plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~wt, key = ~key) %>%
        layout(dragmode = "select",height = 500)
    }
  })
```

EDIT: ggplotly and plotly have the same big height and don't overlap the text output provided that the height in ui is bigger than height in ggplotly layout argument:

```
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    key <- row.names(mtcars)
    if (identical(input$plotType, "ggplotly")) {
      p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, colour = factor(vs), key = key)) + 
        geom_point()
      ggplotly(p) %>% layout(dragmode = "select", height=800)
    } else {
      plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~wt, key = ~key) %>%
        layout(dragmode = "select")
    }
  })

plotlyOutput("plot", height = 800)
```

[image]

Comment: However, I didn't understand why ggplotly(p) %>% layout(dragmode = "select", height = 700) didn't work for you

Comment: It does work. But it doesnt answer the question. The issue with this solution is, that the `ggplotly` is overplotting the `output$hover`-object.

Comment: Is it the same if you try both layout(dragmode = "select", height = 700) and plotlyOutput("plot", height = 700)? I tried bigger plots, they adjusted fine.

Comment: Thanks! Your update did the trick. I will just edit your code a bit to clarify.

Comment: It is weird I tried something like this before. But I suppose the `height` and `width` values in `layout` and `plotOutput` need to be the same to keep it from overplotting. In addition I also tried putting `height`- and `width`-statements into `ggplotly` instead of `layout`. But I guess that gets overwritten.