# Dynamic height of shiny ggplotly plot

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly, ggplotly

I have a `ggplotly` output based on `geom_col()` for which the number of bars varies significantly. I'd like to configure it so the spacing between bars (and therefore also the bar width) remains constant no matter how many bars there are, which means changing the plot height.  Below is based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45236144/1156245) but has no effect for me.  Any suggestions appreciated.

```
require(tidyverse)
require(shiny)
require(plotly)

ui = fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(width = 3, 
      sliderInput('count', 'count', min = 3, max = 100, value = 100, step = 25)
  ),
  mainPanel(width = 9, 
      div(plotlyOutput("plot", height = '200vh'), 
          style='height:90vh !important; overflow:auto !important; background-color:yellow;')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$plot = renderPlotly({
    d = data.frame(x = head(sentences, input$count), y = rlnorm(input$count, meanlog = 5))
    p = d %>% ggplot(aes(fct_reorder(x, y), y)) +
      geom_col(width = 0.1, col='grey90') + geom_point(size = 2) + 
      coord_flip() +
      theme_minimal(base_size = 12) + theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank())
    pltly = ggplotly(p) %>% layout(xaxis = list(side ="top" ))
    pltly$height = nrow(d) * 15
    pltly
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server,
         options = list(launch.browser = FALSE))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify width/height in `ggplotly()` or `plot_ly()`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui = fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(width = 3, 
               sliderInput('count', 'count', min = 3, max = 100, value = 100, step = 25)
  ),
  mainPanel(width = 9, 
            plotlyOutput("plot"),
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot = renderPlotly({
    d = data.frame(x = head(sentences, input$count), y = rlnorm(input$count, meanlog = 5))
    p = d %>% ggplot(aes(fct_reorder(x, y), y)) +
      geom_col(width = 0.1, col='grey90') + geom_point(size = 2) + 
      coord_flip() +
      theme_minimal(base_size = 12) + theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank())
    pltly = ggplotly(p, height = nrow(d) * 15) %>% layout(xaxis = list(side ="top" ))
    pltly
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser = TRUE))
```

However, you might want to specify a bigger minimum height, using the first option, the plot becomes quite narrow.

Comment: I'd already tried that but guess my `ui` code was defeating it. Thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure? For me it also works with your original UI code (if `height` is called in `ggplotly`).

Comment: I think my height calculation was way off.